# Dynamic filter with Django in detail view

Tags: django

I have two models: rooms and holdings. Rooms is a list of rooms, and holdings is a list of things stored in those rooms.

I would to have a detail page (with the generic DetailView) for each room, showing some information from the rooms model about that room and all the records in the holdings model that match that room. The first part was relatively easy, but I can't figure out how to filter the holdings and display the result on the detail page.

Here's what I have so far:

*models.py*

```
class rooms(models.Model):
    room = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100, help_text='Room/storage area ID')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Location', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('room-detail', args=[str(self.room)])

class holdings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey('rooms', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Contact', null=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey('surveys', help_text='Survey ID, Cruise ID, FACS ID, or FAN', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room}, {self.contact}, {self.survey}'
```

*views.py*

```
class RoomDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = rooms

def get_queryset(self):
    self.room = get_object_or_404(rooms, room=self.kwargs['room'])
    return holdings.objects.filter(room=self.room)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['room'] = self.room
    return context
```

*rooms_detail.html*

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h3>Room Detail </h3>
  <p></p>
  <p><strong>Room: </strong>{{ rooms.room }}</p>
  <p><strong>Location:</strong> {{ rooms.location }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

That gives me a KeyError with exception value 'room' for the line `self.room = get_object_or_404(rooms, room=self.kwargs['room'])`. I'm new to Django and can't figure out where to go from here, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason, you shouldn't specify a primary key for a model, because Django then creates one for you automatically: *some_model.id*. *some_model.pk* always points to the primary key, regardless of it's name. In you rooms model, `room.pk` is synonymous with `room.room`

Every override in the Detail View you do is unnecessary:

```
class RoomDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = rooms
    template_name = 'rooms_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'room'  # to access the room via  {{ room }} in the
                                  # template and not the generic {{ object }}
```

How does the DetailView know which room to retrieve? By the primary key - for that you should show your `urls.py`.

It should be something like:

```
# ...
path('rooms/<str:pk>', views.RoomDetailView.as_view(), name='room-detail'),
# ...
```

You can access holdings from a room via the `related_name`, which is generated automatically in your case: `a_room_instance.holdings_set.all()`. You can access that in the template as well!

By the way: It's good practice to follow PEP8 coding conventions - class names (hence models) should be in CapWords.

Comment: Where should I put `a_room_instance.holdings_set.all()` and how would I access that in the template?

Comment: It was just in example. In the RoomDetailView, you can iterate over this room's holdings via `{% for holding in room.holdings_set.all %}{{ holding }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Awesome, that worked and that example will help me a ton. Thanks. So much simpler than [the example from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).